# Execute in different databases in one stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two databases on my SQL server. is that possible to use one stored procedure to call two different databases to receive the data?

Below is an example.

```
    @product AS nvarchar(max) = NULL
BEGIN 
    IF @product= 'iPhone'
    BEGIN
        USE [iPhone Database]
    END 
    ELSE IF @product ='Samsung'
    BEGIN
        USE [samsung Database]
    END

    SELECT * 
    FROM Product
END
```

I'm new to SQL, thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use `USE` in a stored procedure. You *could*, however, use 3 part naming to reference the object(s) inside the `IF` but, honestly, this looks like a design flaw, and you should have 1 database not 2. If you start adding more manufactures and want more databases per manufacturer this starts to scale terribly. Fix your design now, while you have the chance.

Comment: do you also have a database for huawei, xiaomi, motorola, and so on... ? And what if a new brand is needed, you have to create again a new database and change this procedure ? This looks like a really really bad idea

Comment: Echoing @GuidoG comment. This is flat out a bad design.

Comment: Hi, currently this is an existing database with huge data. what I want to do is try to receive data from the current existing database only. I just wonder if can i use one stored procedure to call another database and execute it. else I need to create a stored procedure in every database and execute it from the store procedure.

Comment: I'm sure it's not actually "huge data", SQL Server is perfectly capable of dealing with many terabytes of data in a single database.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the simple way to do this is you can create a view with query of two database that union together

```
CREATE VIEW dataview AS
SELECT * FROM DB1.tb1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM DB2.tb2
```

Then you can query and select data in you stored procedure.

Comment: That won't work. They need to be three part names, i.e. `DB1.dbo.tb1` or `DB1..tb1`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is a bad design, although I'm not sure how you arrived at it. Secondly the code you posted is not a stored procedure (it has no `create procedure` in it). Anyway here are a few ways to do what you want:

**A. use a view (as posted in the prior answer)**

```
CREATE VIEW EverythingView
AS 
SELECT 'iPhone' as ProductType, * FROM [iPhone Database]..Product
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Samsung' as ProductType, * FROM [samsung Database]..Product
```

now you can run this:

```
SELECT * FROM EverythingView WHERE ProductType = 'iPhone'
```

**B. Embed it in the proc**

This can suffer from various issues around parameter sniffing. Not recommended

```
CREATE PROC MyProc 
@product AS nvarchar(4000) = NULL
AS

BEGIN 

IF @product= 'iPhone'
    SELECT * FROM [iPhone Database]..Product

IF @product= 'Samsung'
    SELECT * FROM [samsung Database]..Product
    
END
```

**C. The right way. Put it in one table**

I don't know how your data arrives in these seperate databases but the best thing to do is have *one* product table with everything in it

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductType = 'iPhone'
```